# ngDisable não valida

Tags: angularjs

Bom dia. Eu tô há um tempo tentando validar o meu formulario, desabilitando o `Button` quando o mesmo for inválido. Já tentei de várias formas, inclusive pesquisando por aqui e seguindo conforme foi falado. Mas ainda nao deu certo.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-disabled="!myForm.timeUpdateModel" data-ng-click="salvar();">Pesquisar</button>
```

Já tentei usando `timeUpdateModel.$invalid`, `timeUpdateModel.$pristine`, tentei buscar pelo nome do `input` `timeUpdate.$invalid` e mesmo assim nenhum deles funciona. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: olá, tente myForm.$invalid e coloque ng-required="true" no seu input se não tiver.

Comment: @FelipeM o ng-required ja tem no input. tentei usar da forma como voce falou. Porém ainda nao funcionou :(

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo a seguinte sintaxe:

nome do formulário + name do componente + propriedade

```
ng-disabled="!myForm.inputName.$valid"
```

e o required deve estar no input tbm.